# Woocommerce Create Account Button not clickable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched all related topics to my problem and I am certain none works for me. Currently on my website, "the create account"  button is not clickable. It literally just becomes grey with a red circle with a red diagonal line through it hovering on the "create account button"  . Thanks in advance. Here's a link to the [My Account Page](https://www.cobblermall.com.ng/my-account) on my website.

Comment: Your create account button is disabled. Please check that you have enabled user registration in your WordPress settings and that there is no other theme option that has disabled this.

Comment: Your theme have some JavaScript errors. First try to solve this errors & may that will automatically solve your problems. Also please read the link to ask more better questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the below script in your footer.php file. Hope this will help you.

```
<script>
jQuery('input[name=register]').attr("disabled",false);
</script>
```